# WiX silent install unable to launch built in .EXE: WiX v3

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I know this might seem like a duplicate, but I have tried almost anything online including the following links below:

When using double click, the installation completes successfully and it launches my EXE which is a WPF UI.

The problem is that if run in the command line, the WiX installer installs but my WPF doesn't launch. There is no driver update. **Note that I have custom switches such as /? /q  /forerestart  /noreboot in my WPF.**

[Launch after install, with no UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871531/launch-after-install-with-no-ui)
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html

**Here is my code below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"><?define INF_INSTALLER_TargetDir=$(var.INF_INSTALLER.TargetDir)?>
    <Product Id="guid here" Name="INF_INSTALLER" Language="1033" Version="1.1.1.3" Manufacturer="Intel Corporation" UpgradeCode="guid here">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"  InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <!--User Agrrement-->
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)EULAsingleuselicense.rtf" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="images\Banner.jpg" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="images\Background.png" />


    <!--Chosing the UI version-->
    <!-- Step 2: Add UI to your installer / Step 4: Trigger the custom action -->
    <!-- UI to installer -->
    <UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
      <!-- Launch the applicaiton -->
      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
    <!--<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch INF INSTALLER" /> -->

    <!-- Step 3: Include the custom action -->
    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#INF_INSTALLER.exe]" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />



    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="INF INSTALLER" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
      <!--<ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" /> -->
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="TempFolder">
        <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="INF_INSTALLER">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="INF_INSTALLER" />
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
          <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)" />
        </Directory>
        <!--<Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />-->
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="guid here">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)" Description="INF INSTALLER" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]INF_INSTALLER.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveApplicationProgramsFolder" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\INF_INSTALLER" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <!--<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="guid here">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)" Description="INF INSTALLER" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]INF_INSTALLER.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" Directory="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\INF_INSTALLER" Name="InstalledCompleted" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>-->
  </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="windowscert.cer" Guid="guid here">
              <File Id="windowscert.cer" Name="windowscert.cer" Source="$(var.INF_INSTALLER_TargetDir)windowscert.cer" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="myinf.inf" Guid="guid here">
              <File Id="myinf.inf" Name="myinf.inf" Source="$(var.INF_INSTALLER_TargetDir)myinf.inf" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="INF_INSTALLER.exe" Guid="guid here">
              <File Id="INF_INSTALLER.exe" Name="INF_INSTALLER.exe" Source="$(var.INF_INSTALLER_TargetDir)INF_INSTALLER.exe" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="INF_INSTALLER.exe.config" Guid="guid here">
              <File Id="INF_INSTALLER.exe.config" Name="INF_INSTALLER.exe.config" Source="$(var.INF_INSTALLER_TargetDir)INF_INSTALLER.exe.config" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="INF_INSTALLER.pdb" Guid="guid here">
              <File Id="INF_INSTALLER.pdb" Name="INF_INSTALLER.pdb" Source="$(var.INF_INSTALLER_TargetDir)INF_INSTALLER.pdb" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>

  <Fragment>

    <CustomAction Id="LaunchFile" FileKey="INF_INSTALLER.exe" ExeCommand="/quiet" Return="asyncNoWait" />

    <Property Id="WixSilentExecCmdLine" Value="/silent" Hidden="yes"/>
    <CustomAction Id="SilentExecExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixSilentExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>

      <Custom Action="LaunchFile" After="InstallFinalize">NOT  Installed</Custom>
      <Custom Action="SilentExecExample" After="TheActionYouWantItAfter"/>
      <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize" />

    </InstallExecuteSequence>


  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Do your silent msiexec statement and create a log file by appending /l*vx [path to log file] because that will give some clues (or error messages) about your executable.

Answer (score 1):

***Faulty Configuration***: This line would never run - regardless of silent or interactive mode:

```xml
<Custom Action="SilentExecExample" After="TheActionYouWantItAfter"/>
```

The After attribute must specify a valid **StandardAction** or **CustomAction** name.

***Silent Mode Failure***: The line below will fail in silent mode because you run it after `InstallFinalize`. In this case it will not run with elevation (unless you launch the setup from an elevated `cmd.exe` prompt) and the setup can therefore not complete (the setup runs elevated only between `InstallInitialize` and `InstallFinalize` in the `InstallExecuteSequence`):

```xml
<Custom Action="LaunchFile" After="InstallFinalize">NOT  Installed</Custom>
```

There are a few more things you should know. Please read the below.

---

***Windows Update Distribution***: For the record, it appears Microsoft wants driver distribution to happen via Windows Update in the future, or at least via a standalone package without the need for an installer.

As of Windows 10, Version 1607:

- **[DIFx tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/ff544838(v=vs.90))** are no longer included in the **WDK** (Windows Driver Kit).

  - [Some important tidbits if you choose to use DIFx anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/difx-guidelines).
- [Windows Hardware Dev Center dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/) is now available for "hardware tasks":

  - `Hardware certification`
  - `Collaborative driver development`
  - `Driver distribution through Windows Update`

---

***Driver Element***: WiX currently has the [**Driver Element**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html) for driver installation. It uses the DIFx framework under the hood - as far as I know. [**A small, practical example found on github.com**](https://github.com/tixsys/esteid/blob/a0be3c31a0390f68f042127f0498e0900d0304a5/packages/windows/trunk/minidriver.wxs). I have never used this feature. [FireGiant's WiX Expansion Pack](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/driver/) features more advanced driver installation support. Never tried by me.

***DPInst.exe***: I am not familiar with **`INF_INSTALLER.exe`** - is that a proprietary component you have created? It is also possible to install signed drivers using the [**`DPInst.exe`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/ff544842(v=vs.90)) tool from the DIFx framework. It can be called via custom actions inside an MSI or it can probably be run directly from Burn (WiX Bundle - in other words not part of an MSI). [**A fairly short example found on github.com**](https://github.com/marrob/MCAN120803/blob/a83b289807ae92321d04a27ba72046d9cdf5f893/Install/%5B15%5DMCAN120803_Driver.wxs).

***A Little Tip***: Searching for `"DPInst.exe http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"` will yield heaps of hits. You can use this github search technique to find help with pretty much anything in my experience. Be critical though, and I would use the time saved to do extra testing. Just my 2 cents.

---

***Some Links***:

- [**Roadmap for Device and Driver Installation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/roadmap-for-device-and-driver-installation--windows-vista-and-later-)
- [Distributing a driver package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/distributing-a-driver-package-win8)
- [Can't seem to get Wix to install driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820598/cant-seem-to-get-wix-to-install-driver)
- [How do I install drivers using Burn and DPInst after MSI installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035367/how-do-i-install-drivers-using-burn-and-dpinst-after-msi-installation)
- https://github.com/trondr/DpInstExitCode2ExitCode
- <del>[Driver installation github](https://github.com/xoware/vpex/blob/727228d7aaf67bec0bd77956984e36dcaee8d818/xokey/win.net/driver-install/Ethernet_Driver.wxs)</del>

Comment: [Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815839/customaction-driverpackageinstall-failing-with-0x80030005/52820791#52820791).